# MySQL threeway triangle query

Tags: mysql

I have a database of teams, schools and assignments. After choosing an assignment, the school (its users anyway) can add a team to an assignment, so that they may start working on the assignment.  The ER-diagram looks like this:
[image: ER-diagram of the database]
**Important:** Even though the setup of the database suggests otherwise, the team<-> assignment relationship is 1:N. A team can work on only one assignment. This is controlled through the ORM-system.

Now here's the catch: there are teams in the database that work on assignments which do not belong to their school: the school choose the assignment, created a team and removed their assignment choice. I need to find the schools (id, name) for which this is the case.

The best query so far that I've managed to come up with is:

```
SELECT schools.school_id, schools.name
FROM schools
LEFT JOIN teams ON schools.school_id = teams.school_id
LEFT JOIN assignment_teams ON teams.team_id = assignment_teams.team_id
LEFT JOIN assignment_schools ON schools.school_id = assignment_schools.school_id
WHERE assignment_teams.assignment_id != assignment_schools.assignment_id;
```

But it doesn't work when I checked the results manually. What's the correct query that I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of these should work, but I have no idea which is the fastest:

1. ```
     SELECT school_id
     FROM teams
     INNER JOIN assignment_teams ON teams.team_id = assignment_teams.team_id
     LEFT JOIN assignment_schools ON assignment_schools.school_id = teams.school_id AND  assignment_schools.assignment_id = assignment_teams.assignment_id
     WHERE assignment_schools.school_id IS NULL
   ```
2. ```
   SELECT school_id
     FROM teams
     INNER JOIN assignment_teams ON teams.team_id = assignment_teams.team_id
     WHERE assignment_id NOT IN (
       SELECT assignment_id
         FROM assignment_schools
         WHERE assignment_schools.school_id = teams.school_id
     )
   ```
3. ```
   SELECT school_id
     FROM teams
     INNER JOIN assignment_teams ON teams.team_id = assignment_teams.team_id
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT *
         FROM assignment_schools
         WHERE assignment_schools.school_id = teams.school_id
         AND assignment_schools.assignment_id = assignment_teams.assignment_id
     )
   ```

Comment: For an analysis of the comparative performance of each query, see [@Quassnoi's blog article](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) on the subject.

Comment: @eggyal I have actually read an article (possibly not that one) on the comparative performance before, but I still prefer profiling.

Comment: As I need this only once (for analysis of the current situation), speed is not important. I picked the simplest query (the first) and it worked like a charm. Thanks!